# How to make a post request within certain time interval automatically using nodejs, axios, ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, ejs

I started learning mern stack few weeks back and got recently struck with the API portion of "How to update the data from API automatically in my ejs template without refreshing or no button click post method".

First step : I implemented a get request for index.ejs.
Second step : I created a const function `fetchJoke` to Fetch a joke at random intervals.

But then I am getting data from API for 10 secs time interval but I wasn't able to update the data in my ejs template without refreshing the page and I need to update it automatically for 10 secs.

```
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

let currentJoke = {}; // Store the current joke

const fetchJoke = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/any?type=twopart");
        currentJoke = response.data;
        console.log(currentJoke);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch joke:", error.message);
    }
};
setInterval(fetchJoke,20000);
fetchJoke();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        Service: currentJoke,
    });
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Running on port ${port}`);
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <% if(locals.Service) {%>
        <h1>
            <%= Service.setup %>
        </h1>     
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically update JS on the client (the webpage/ rendered ejs template that's served by your Express server in this example) you'll need to deploy some kind of script within your ejs template that fetches the joke.

You can either refetch the joke from it's source directly (https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/any?type=twopart), or make a new API endpoint on your Express server to handle this for you. Below is an example of the additional Express endpoint:

```js
app.get("/api/joke", (req, res) => res.json(currentJoke));
```

Fetching this from your Express server now will return whatever the value of `currentJoke` is on the server.

In your ejs template you'd need to set up the following JS script in order to handle this automatically:

```html
<script>
  const updateJoke = async () => {
    // fetch request to get the joke from your Express server
    const jokeRes = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/joke");
    const joke = await jokeRes.json();

    // actually update the header (for greater specificity you can attach an id to your h1 element and use document.getElementById()
    const headerEl = document.querySelector("h1");
    if(headerEl) headerEl.innerText = joke.setup;
  }

  // call this function every 20 seconds to match the update interval on the server
  setInterval(updateJoke, 20000);
</script>
```